# Making internal rest requests non-blocking?

Tags: rest-api

I'm making a call to an internal endpoint in order to try and speed up a task.

I don't need to wait for the task (that awaits at that endpoint) to complete for my script to move on, but it's still waiting to finish. I'm using the following:

```
$argsForRequest = array(
'agency_code' => '1234',
'another_param_here' => $myVar,
'timeout'   => 0.01,
'blocking'  => false,
'sslverify' => false,
);

$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'POST', '/my/custom/endpoint' );
$request->set_query_params( $argsForRequest );
$response = rest_do_request( $request );
```

Any idea on what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution ?

Comment: @GnanasekaranLoganathan Yup I posted my solution.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**`rest_do_request` does not make a HTTP request to the REST API.** `rest_do_request` handles a request object directly. `WP_REST_Request` and `rest_do_request` are for handling requests, not making them. This is why your attempt to make it non-blocking failed.

If you want to make a non-blocking request to the REST API, you have to make a HTTP request using `wp_remote_post` to the desired endpoint.